# How can I send custom commands to a process when my EC2 instance gets "shutdown"?

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

I'm hosting a Minecraft server on an EC2 instance & I'm also using Google Cloud Functions to stop the instance every night via the AWS SDK. Every time the instance gets stopped via my cloud function, I want to make sure all players are kicked from the server, & the server process is sent SIGTERM. I need some way to detect when the instance is being "stopped".